# Deploying a Java FX databse Application

Tags: sqlite, javafx, deployment

I am building a Java FX based Standalone application with SQLite DB in Netbeans IDE and wish to deploy the app to a native installation package (exe / msi).

I've surfed the web too much for the same and found a few methods with WIX Toolset & Inno Setup Inno Setup 6 has some issues while building the native package.

Also when I tried to do an msi bundle, I found that my database and other resource sub directories were not being bundled.

my project directory structure is as follows :

- Project_Directory

  - build
  - database

    - db.sqlite
  - dist

    - lib
    - application.jar
  - nbproject
  - src
  - Logo.png

It would very much kind & grateful if I get a solution for this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you actually want the database embedded as a _resource_? Keep in mind that makes it read-only.

Comment: Actually I want the Database to be deployed along the package because I'm using SQLite, (that has a .sqlite DB file).

So the file must be must be on the app directory in Database->db.sqlite that will be always accessed.

Comment: @Slaw I would be very much thankful if you can help me out Sir...!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still not very clear on what you want to happen. In what way do you want the database "along" the package? Does that mean a _resource_? Does that mean included in the installation directory (yet not a resource)? And if you don't want the database as a resource, then why are you attempting to bundle it with your application? What are you doing with this database? Because if you write to it then it may make more sense to create the database at run-time at some known location (e.g. user home, appdata, etc.). If you only read from it then why not make it a resource?